# Inconsistent behavior in java date formatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Either I'm missing something completely obvious or making unwarranted assumptions about the behavior of SimpleDateFormat.

I'd assume that it ought to be symmetric, right? If I have

```
SimpleDateFormatter formatter;
String datestr=...
Date d = formatter.parse(datestr);
String s=formatter.format(d);
```

I should get back my original String. However -

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "E MMM dd HH:mm:dd zz yyyy";
String test = "Mon Nov 29 09:53:24 EST 2010";
long l = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(test).getTime();
System.out.println(test);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(new Date(l)));
```

prints out :

Mon Nov 29 09:53:24 EST 2010

Wed Nov 24 09:53:24 EST 2010

How am I losing 5 days?

Answer (score 6):

```
"E MMM dd HH:mm:dd zz yyyy";
       ^^       ^^
```

Comment: guess it was the "obvious" category err. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm good at debbuging this stuff though. 5 days is a random amount of time (as in not related to a time zone or something). So I just looked for 24 somewhere else in the parsed string =P